# Location update through socket in Android

Tags: android, sockets, socket.io

I am trying to update and retrieve locations through socket for reliable connection. How can I connect to a server from my app and what kind of server should I use?

Comment: `retrive locations through socket `??? What do you have in mind by that?

Comment: I want to retrieve location details(lat,lng) through socket as i am implementing a online tracking app.@greenapps

Comment: Retrieve them from where? What's behind the socket? –

Comment: from server of course and the details will be of others who are using the app .@greenapps

Comment: `How can I connect to a server from my app` Through a socket?